# Chrome not removing typed text on autofill selection

Tags: php, html, input

Some of my users are encountering a strange issue, specifically on Chrome Mobile, that I have been unable to replicate myself.

When filling out an input field (a search field, specifically, that is a GET form) they may start typing a word, for instance 'E' and then choose 'Egg' from their browser autofill and the text in the box will become 'EggE' (adding the typed text onto the end of the selected autofill.)

The code itself is simple and I feel like this has more to do with mobile Chrome, but I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to prevent it on my end within the code.

```
<form method="get">
<input type="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for Item Name">
</form>
```

Comment: This is less of an HTML/PHP question, more of a browser / mobile handling of an application. Nothing in that HMTL code would specifically cause this. It also depends if they're referring to autofill (where they've typed a value in before), or predictive text on their phones. I've had issues with predictive text applications on android that have done the same issue you are referring to before.